# angular 4 bootstrap tabs fill parent element full size

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, ngfor

I have some bootstrap tabs that are generated be angular 4 `*ngFor` directive from an array in the typescript file, 
this array is filled from the server so I cant guess how many elements (tabs) i will have,
how can I ensure that those tab elements will fill the whole space of the parent element ?

If they where rows and columns , it would be easier I think because the columns `div` will have `class="col"`, but how to create the same effect if they were tabs.

**this is the HTML:**

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="list" role="presentation" routerLinkActive='active' *ngFor="let tab of tabsHeadings">
    <a role="tab" [routerLink]="['/about-us']" [queryParams]="{ tab: tab }" queryParamsHandling="merge" (click)="changeTab(tab)">{{tab}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and I have some CSS classes that I need to stay with the tabs. (if I change the whole thing into `divs` and then use bootstrap `rows and columns` the behavior and style of the tabs will be change)

Now I am using `width: 33.3%` on each tab, because ideally (and in most cases) there will be 3 tabs maximum, but in some cases there will be less

**CSS:**

```css
  .tab .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #153967;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    font-family: Industry;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: 18%;
    /*padding-left: 19%;
    padding-right: 19%;*/
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs > li a {
    color: #153967;
    font-family: Industry;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs > li a:hover, .tab .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #153967;
    /*padding-bottom:5px;*/
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #153967;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .tab .tab-content {
    color: #153967;
    padding-left: 18%;
    padding-right: 18%;
    margin-top: 1.6em;
  }
  .list {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
```

Can any one help in this please ?

Comment: Hello, why don't you ask the (array.lenght) to the server ?

Comment: hi, and then what? I can easily get the array size, but the array size is not constant, it changes by time, how can i configure the the tab elements to change according to the array size to which each element have equal width and all elements fill 100% of the parent width